# An $n$th root inequality: $\sqrt[n]{n} < 1 + \sqrt{2/n}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, radicals

> Prove that for any positive integer $n$,
>
> $$n^{1/n}  < 1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}.$$

This is due to Viktors Linis, *Crux Mathematicorum* (which was at the time called *Eureka*), Vol. 2, No. 2, February 1976, p. 29.

**Hint:**

> Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: Err... couldn't you answer this yourself?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I could have.

Comment: So, you're sharing?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff objection: none of your questions have to do with the topic.

Comment: @MathApprentice What are you objecting?

Comment: This is also given in Larson's *Problem solving through problems* as problem 7.1.15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\right)^n>1+C_n^2*\frac{2}{n}=n$$